# simple jquery $(this).next() not behaving in IE

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, this, slidetoggle

I have this markup

```
<h2>Title</h2>
<div class="info-content">
<p>some code in here too</p>
</div>
```

and this jquery

```
(function($) { 
    $(".info-content").hide(); 
    $("h2").click(function(){
        $(this).next().slideToggle("normal");
    });
})(jQuery);
```

which, in any browser apart from IE6+, toggles the .info-content open and closed.

Any ideas why this wouldn't work in IE? I'm assuming its something quite simple but I've been trying to figure it out for a while now.

Any help would be great,

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`next()` might be returning a text node.

Try `$(this).nextAll("p:first")`

Comment: spot on! $(this).nextAll(".info-content") worked perfectly. Thankyou very much @SLaks

Answer (score 1):

or you can do

```
$(this).find('info-content').slideToggle("normal);
```

Comment: Digging up quite an old question here, but that would surely toggle ALL `.info-content` elements? The `next` was to only catch the following element in the DOM (if I remember correctly).

Thanks for the response though!